# AJAX contact form trouble

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a problem with an AJAX-based contact form. I'm stuck at the PHP code. The code doesn't send the e-mail and doesn't notifies the user about troubles. 
Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="contact_form">
     <form method="post" action="mail.php" name="contact-form" id="contact-form">
         ...
            <div id="response"></div>
         ...
            <input class="contact_button button" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Send!">
         ...
     </form>
</div>
```

And the JS:

```
 ...
 $(paraTag).append('<input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" value="Trimite" />');

 $('#main input#submit').click(function() {
 ...

    $.ajax({
          type: 'post',
          url: 'mail.php',
          data: 'name=' + name + '&email=' + email +'&subject='+ subject +'&message=' + message,

          success: function(results) {  
                $('div#response').html(results).css('display', 'block');        

          }
    });
 }
```

What should I write in PHP for returning the response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#main input#submit').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
          type: 'post',
          url: 'mail.php',
          data: {'name':name,'email':email,'subject':subject,'message':message},
          success: function(results) {  
                $('div#response').html(results).css('display', 'block');        

          }
    });
 }
```

//In your mail.php

```
print_r($_POST);
```

Will give you the posted array via ajax.And do the rest of the code by getting the posted array